# rsyslog - assigning a modified property to a cee variable

Tags: rsyslog

So I'm going nuts trying to get a sortable timestamp from rsyslog into a CEE variable which will go to ElasticSearch.  Right now I'm using:

```
set $!tgen = $timegenerated;
```

from which the field looks like "Apr  4 13:52:26" -- useless for sorting.

From http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/property_replacer.html it looks like rsyslog has a syntax to do exactly what I want:

```
%timegenerated:::unixtimestamp%
```

However this is for string templates and I'm not sure how to assign the result of this to a CEE variable as above.  Looks like rsyslog's different languages are coming into play here, and you can't easily mix them.

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: should note I'm using development rsyslog 7.3.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that template constructs are just that: template constructs. They can be used inside string templates, but not assigned to a variable (this has deep technical and historical reasons). Unfortunately, there currently the date conversion you are asking for is not available yet via scripting. It may make sense to request it via the mailing list (but I am rather busy at the moment - will see if I can fit it in, but than the ML is a better communication method).

Comment: cool thanks. Seems like others would want something like this too.